# Timeout Error on Powershell script querying SQL DB - Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I am receiving the message on a Powershell file that is SQLing a SQL DB.  The query worked for about 1.5 years and I assume it started timing out because the data set that it is pulling as part of the query has exponentially grown over this time.  The error message I am receiving is:

> Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

However, when adding $SqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 0 to the query as shown below it is still timing out after the same amount of time.  The remote query setting in SQL is the default 600 seconds.  It would almost seem as if there is an issue/permission at the network-level that is not allowing the information in this query to dictate the amount of timeout.  I have also added an infinite timeout to the SQL query in case there was a DB DEADLOCK, but that does not appear to be the issue.  When I run the exact same query with less data being returned, it runs fine.

Why would the command below of an infinite timeout be ignored?

```
   `

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; Integrated Security = True"
    $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName;User Id=$SQLUserName;Password=$SQLDBPWD"

    $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

    $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
    $SqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 0

    $SqlConnection.Open()

    if ($SqlConnection.State -eq 'Open')
{
$message = "SQL Connection established"
$message | out-file {filepath}:\{filepath}\{filename} -append
###SQL statements go here


$sql = "{large, complex SQL query here}"

$adapter = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter ($sql, $SqlConnection)

$adapter.Fill($table) 


$table |ConvertTo-CSV -delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation|  %{$_.Replace('"','')} | out-file {filepath}:\{filepath}\{filename}



$SqlConnection.Close();
```

`

Comment: I cant see a query string and it looks like you have your code in the example twice. Are you having a timeout error running the exact code above? If so then it isnt query based, it is connection based.

Comment: And just a matter of caution, do you have $sqlConnection.Close() ?

Comment: Why not use Invoke-Sqlcmd? Save all this code.

Comment: Hi Everyone, thank you for your assistance.  I have modified the post to make it more clear...not sure why it duplicated the code before.  I also included the close statement.  Please keep in mind that this is only a piece of a much larger PowerShell Script.

Comment: It is also worth noting that we reconfigured & doubled the WSMAN limits just in case (ref https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/configuring-wsman-limits/). In reality the IdleTimeout is 180000, which is longer than the amount of time I am getting prior to receiving the PowerShell "Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding." message, but I figured it couldn't hurt. It didn't resolve the issue though.  Any help as to other timeout settings at the network or permissions level would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!